# Get eigenvalues from tridiagonal symmetric matrix in R like in lapack dstev

Tags: r, lapack

I was wondering if it is possible to diagonalize a symmetric tridiagonal matrix (real) in R **passing only the diagonal vectors** so you can avoid generating the complete matrix and use an optimized routine like `dstev` or `dsteqr` from Lapack

By the moment I know that for the R function `eigen` you can just specify whether the matrix is symmetric or not.

Is it worth to try to access directly to lapack or just do the a manual algorithm for this special case, in order to get good performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and trial and error I found solutions to this problem by myself.

There are native ways to call external code in R, the routines `.Fortran` and `.C` can execute compiled code from those languages without the need of an intermediate layer.

The following code explains how to use the LAPACK routine `dstev` in order to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors from a symmetric matrix. To do this, it is necessary to have a BLAS/LAPACK implementation installed on your machine, such as Atlas, OpenBLAS or MKL.

```
dyn.load("/usr/lib/liblapack.so")  #Load Lapack
Jobz <- as.character('V')            #Get The eigenvalues and Eigenvectors
N <- as.integer(10)                  #Matrix Dimension
D <- runif(10)                       #Diagonal
E <- runif(9)                        #Upper (and lower) diagonal
Z <- array(0.0,N*N)                  #storage for eigenvectors
Ldz <- N                             #Leading dimension of Z (in our case number of rows)
Work <- array(0.0,2*N)               #Storage for processing
info <- as.integer(0)                #Info flag

#Call the fortran routine
res<-.Fortran("dstev", Jobz, N, D, E, Z, Ldz, Work, info)

#Extract the information
evalues <- res[[3]]
evectors <- matrix(res[[5]],N,N)
```

Comment: Fine. You could have compared with `eigen`.  The eignenvalues and vectors are in reverse order compared to `eigen`.